# NHibernate Linq Query Where(x => x is Base Class) doesn't get derived objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Let's say I have the following structure, mapped with a discriminator (Table per hierarchy):

```
    Entity (abstract, no discriminator)
      |
    Animal (abstract, no discriminator)
    /    \
Dog (1)  Cat(2)
```

If I query on this using Linq to NHibernate:

```
.Where(x => x.Entity is Animal)
```

I get no results. When looking at the generated query I expected to see:

```
where type in (1, 2)
```

But instead I got this:

```
where type='animal'
```

Animal is abstract and doesn't even have a discriminator, so the generated query is meaningless.

Digging a bit deeper I found that the query is translated internally to something similar to `WHERE x.class=animal` in HQL. Is this a bug in Linq to NHibernate? Or is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I <s>fixed this bug</s> added this feature to NHibernate. The changes are [here](https://github.com/alexDevBR/nhibernate-core/tree/NH-3946) and can be built from source. I issued a pull request so hopefully this will be working soon.

**Update**: It was [merged](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/553), and should be available in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get expected result when using

```
session.Query<Animal>().Select(a => a.yourXEntity).ToList()
```

Or

```
session.Query<Animal>().SelectMany(a => a.yourXEntityCollection).ToList()
```

instead? Those one should handle polymorphism.

While your lambda `x.Entity is Animal` gets very likely translated to [HQL](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryhql.html#queryhql-where) `x.Entity.class = Animal` which does not handle polymorphism and takes only the discriminator value of specified class, which defaults to its class name.

Comment: If I do `session.Query<Animal>.ToList()` I get the expected query, `type in (1,2)`. If I do the queries in your answer, I think it also works. The problem is only with `.Where(x => x.Entity is Animal)`. I could do .Where(x => session.Query<Animal>().Select(a => a.Id).Contains(x.Entity.Id)), but then instead of a simple `where type in (1,2)` I get a complex subquery `where id in (select id from ...)`.